# How do I get tor to use a global proxy?

Tags: proxy, tor

I'm trying to set up my ubuntu system to use TOR globally, in all applications, but I can't seem to find any instructions for the newer releases, so everything I find it years out of date. Right now, I have TOR installed from the TOR repositories, as well as privoxy. I followed this set of commands, which don't seem to make much sense anyway.

```
    sudo aptitude install tor
    sudo  vim /etc/tor/torrc
    sudo  vim /etc/privoxy/config
    comment out: “logfile logfile” and “jarfile jarfile”
    find: listen-address 127.0.0.1:8118
    add (on next line): forward-socks4a / localhost:9050 . (including the period)
    sudo /etc/init.d/tor restart && sudo /etc/init.d/privoxy restart
```

from this link: https://vocf.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/using-tor-in-ubuntu-torify-our-life/ Basically, I added these two lines to my `/etc/privoxy/config`:

```
listen-address 127.0.0.1:8118
forward-socks4a / localhost:9050 .
```

but I keep getting this error message when I restart the TOR/privoxy server:

```
Sep 02 19:29:42.471 b780c8d0 Error: Ignoring unrecognized directive  'forward-socks:4a / localhost:9050 .' (314890724ul) in line 729 in  configuration file (/etc/privoxy/config)
```

I assume the error is because the instructions are for *buntu 6.06, but I can't find any more recent instructions. Any help here? There must be some way of doing this in more recent versions of Ubuntu, right?

Thank you!

Comment: tor itself recommends `polipo` to `privoxy`. Have you tried to setup with `polipo` ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/92911/tor-check-failed-though-vidalia-shows-green-onion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an issue around the spacing in the forward directive. There should be a sample one in the config file prefixed with a '#'. I would comment the one you have and uncomment the preexisting one.

Comment: I had a small error (based on the sample in the file) in `/etc/privoxy/config`: the `forward-socks4a` had a colon between `socks` and `4a` which isn't in the sample. However, now I don't get an error message when I restart; it just says `fail` in red. I tried using `forward-socks4a`, `forward-socks5` but nothing works.