# Can't run Tor from terminal

Tags: proxy, tor

So... I can't run Tor from my terminal. I have tried many different things, but I couldn't make it run. Once, it didn't stop to run when I wanted to. At my other attempt I also ended up failing because when it stopped to run I couldn't connect myself to the Internet. I hope you can help me here guys.

To be more specific, what I mean by "can't run from terminal" is that I can't hide my IP if I'm installing a program from terminal, for instance. Or if I'm running another program that is making a connection with the internet, my IP isn't being hidden. What I want is to make Tor work for all my programs. So my IP would be hidden in any connection with the internet.

Comment: Could be a bit more specific about the program you are using and what it means when you are writing "hide your IP from terminal"? It would be nice to see the command you are using and the output. You can hide all sensitive aspects, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run tor with all the connections you need to configure `tor` and `polipo`. See [Tor check failed though Vidalia shows green onion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92911/tor-check-failed-though-vidalia-shows-green-onion) for configuring `tor` and `polipo`. Basically what you need to do is configure manual proxy in your network settings  and apply it system wide after that. I guess that will work.

[image]

Comment: Hum... I tried it but that didn't work. I still can't hide my IP from terminal. However, now when I stop all services and put the proxy settings into "none" I still can connect to the internet and the fact that I was not able to that was really bothering me, so... THANK YOU VERY MUCH! = )

Comment: Did you try tor with specific programs and checked ? What do you get when you run a terminal command with `usewithtor COMMAND` ?

Comment: I didn't know about that command... How do I use it? I typed it and it showed me this:
"ERROR: COMMAND is setuid. usewithtor will not work on a setuid executable."

Comment: Have you checked tor for firefox/chromium ? See here for more info:  https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work either... Firefox, Chrome, they just go like tor wasn't able or something like that. = /

Comment: And it is. For make it work in firefox, for instance, I have to use Tor Button. If I just simply run commands in the termianl and change proxy settings, these things go like nothing ever happened. I don't know what to do anymore. I can use TOR, but I wanted to make it run between the connection of the terminal with the internet. = /

Answer (score 0):

There's this concept I learned a while ago from a YouTube video, about how to create a custom command to run Sublime Text on [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/). I apply it to pretty much any application I want now. I made [a bit of a guide on GitHub](https://github.com/DinnEferet/OpenBash). Might help with running your Tor, as long as you know exactly which directory you installed it in.

Comment: We need the steps here, not a link to them. Please [edit] your answer and include :)