# Why Isn't Tor Working?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, proxy, tor

I installed Tor & Polipo via the Software Center. I followed instructions found at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92911/tor-check-failed-though-vidalia-shows-green-onion) (but since the config file was 404, I used a config from [Tor + Polipo 5 Minute Install Guide Ubuntu 11.10](http://dangertux.wordpress.com/tutorials/tor-polipo-5-minute-install-guide-ubuntu-11-0411-10/)).

Tor & Polipo are working properly. I set my network to manual proxy & added the 127.0.0.1:8118 for all but socks (which is 9050). Those are the ports set in the Polipo config file. Still, neither Google Chrome nor Firefox are using Tor when I browse.

I expected to have this working in 5 minutes but it's been over an hour. I'm very confused -- What am I missing???

Comment: It is not a solution but I have had success with the [tor browser bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en). Unless you have a good reason to route all your traffic through tor then i wouldnt really recommend it as speed is severely reduced.

Comment: install tor from here & check the config its working perfectly here http://www.webupd8.org/2009/09/how-to-install-tor-in-ubuntu-debian.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox you should have [Torbutton](https://torproject.org/torbutton).  Besides integrating with SOCKS and Polipo, it comes with many security options.

It's [not recommend](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/google-chrome-incognito-mode-tor-and-fingerprinting) to use Chrome with Tor.

Comment: Well it works now, after getting the Tor button for Firefox. I'm hopin' to use it for things outside the browser too, but as long as I can browse privately, I'll be happy. Thanks!